# Edit Polygon Added with map.addLayer in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, polygon, mapbox-gl-js

I want to edit polygon which i have added using map.addLayer() on mapbox.

the code:

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'maine'+id,
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Polygon',
                'coordinates': coords
            }
        }
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#088',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mapbox GL Drawing Library is used to draw/edit the shapes.

You have added the polygon as a map layer. Editing the layer in drawing mode directly seems not possible. Here is a possible way

1. You need to hide the layer first.
2. Get the Polygon data from layer source
3. Init the drawing mode and add a new polygon to drawing manager with the polygon data
4. Once the editing finished, update the layer source with the edited polygon data from drawing manager
5. Remove the polygon from the drawing manager
6. Show the updated layer

You need to use the `add` method to draw an existing shape.

```
draw.add({
            'id': 'polygon-3355',
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Polygon',
                'coordinates': [[[-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
                    [-66.96466, 44.8097],
                    [-68.03252, 44.3252],
                    [-69.06, 43.98],
                    [-70.11617, 43.68405],
                    [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
                    [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
                    [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
                    [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
                    [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
                    [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
                    [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
                    [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
                    [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
                    [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
                    [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
                    [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
                    [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
                    [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
                    [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]]]
            }
        });
```

Library Link:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw

API Methods Reference:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Show drawn polygon area</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    .calculation-box {
        height: 75px;
        width: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.9/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.9/mapbox-gl-draw.css' type='text/css'/>
<div id='map'></div>
<div class='calculation-box'>
    <p>Draw a polygon using the draw tools.</p>
    <div id='calculated-area'></div>
</div>

<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZWRlbnJheWdhcmRuZXIiLCJhIjoiRlZRVlhqOCJ9.tDrWaeNRbMCtXAovQLYuzA';

    /* eslint-disable */
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
        center:  [-70.11617, 43.68405],
        zoom: 5
    });

    var draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        }
    });
    map.addControl(draw);

    map.on('draw.create', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.update', updateArea);


    draw.add({
        'id': 'polygon-3355',
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [[[-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
                [-66.96466, 44.8097],
                [-68.03252, 44.3252],
                [-69.06, 43.98],
                [-70.11617, 43.68405],
                [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
                [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
                [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
                [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
                [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
                [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
                [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
                [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
                [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
                [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
                [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
                [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
                [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
                [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
                [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]]]
        }
    });

    function updateArea(e) {
        var data = draw.getAll();
        var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
        if (data.features.length > 0) {
            var area = turf.area(data);
            // restrict to area to 2 decimal points
            var rounded_area = Math.round(area*100)/100;
            answer.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + rounded_area + '</strong></p><p>square meters</p>';
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML = '';
            if (e.type !== 'draw.delete') alert("Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!");
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Hussain Ujjainwala Do you want to just update the polygon layer or edit as drawing mode?